# Javac misses my main .java file but no others

Tags: java, javac

I am trying to compile my `.java` files into `.class` files. For some reason, it just refuses to compile one specific `.java` file.

I am using the following in command line:

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath src -cp src/Main/*.java
```

And all of the `.java` files create corresponding `.class` files in my bin directory, except for my `main.java` file. Is there any reason for this to be happening?

Comment: " it just refuses to compile one specific .java file" --> It should print reason for refusal on your console.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -lR src` / the output of the compiler?

Comment: `-cp src/Main/*.java` - it makes no sense to specify `src/Main/*.java` as the classpath. The classpath is for finding compiled classes, not for finding source files.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=751056 this is something to do with a compiler bug.

For me, the javac was only missing the 1st file alphabetically in the source directory. I fixed the problem by creating a blank file called aa.java in the source directory and then my main file (which happened to be the 1st alphabetical file) compiled correctly.